# I cannot submit the comments for multi posts in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a feed and in this feed have posts and each post have comments, Now I can submit a comment for just the first post but when I try to come to the second or third post and submit comment this error rise

> ValueError: The view videos.views.add_comment_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I thought that the problem with the posts id conflict with each other so I passed all the comment fields to the template and the same error still happen. "this problem happen with any post except the first one"

My comments view

```
   comment_form = PostCommentForm(request.POST )
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.author = request.user
            user_comment.save()
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            user = request.user.username

            return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user})
```

My Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My comments model

```
class PostCommentIDE(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ide_com')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My comments Form

```
class PostCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = PostCommentIDF
        fields = {'post', 'content'}
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'rounded-0  form-control', 'rows': '1', 'placeholder': 'Comment', 'required': 'True', })
        }
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        PostCommentIDF.objects.rebuild()
        return super(PostCommentForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `if comment_form.is_valid()` your form is not valid, it is expecting a else block, add logic when form is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I won't know why I can submit the first comment successfully but  I cannot submit a comment for the second post or third

Comment: check your `comment_form.errors` to get the errors.

Comment: There is no anything happend but this shows in the terminal ` "POST /video/post/add/comment HTTP/1.1" 500 70598`

Answer (score 0):

when form is not valid the form is returning None.
you should return something(for example returning error messages) when form is not valid.

```
comment_form = PostCommentForm(request.POST)
if comment_form.is_valid():
    user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    user_comment.author = request.user
    user_comment.save()
    result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
    user = request.user.username

    return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user})
else:
    # do stuff here if form is not valid
    return JsonResponse({'result': 'Something went wrong.'})
```